# Is it possible to share AAD authentication cookie between two web applications on the same site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, signalr, owin-middleware, azure-authentication

***Question*** Is it possible for a back-end-web-app to accept and pick up the user identity from the AAD authentication cookie generated by signing in to a front-end-web-app?

***Background*** I want to achieve an Azure Active Directory single sign on experience for a JavaScript SignalR client but my current solution requires the user to sign in twice. Once to access the web app hosting the js-client and then again so that the js-client-app can access the back-end.

**Desired solution** with SSO AAD Authentication

1. Front-end *(OWIN/MVC/JavaScript)*

   - AAD authentication to identify the user - *implemented*
   - JS SignalR client includes the auth cookie in the server requests - *works by default*
2. Back-end *(OWIN/SignalR PersistentConnection)*

   - Identify the user via the the encrypted .AspNetCookies cookie from the front-end authentication that is included in the SignalR requests.
   - *the cookie is not accepted and the debug output from OWIN is Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware Warning: 0 : Unprotect ticket failed*

**Attempted Back-End Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureAuth( IAppBuilder app )
   app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType( CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
   app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
   app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
       new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
           {
              ClientId = clientId,
              Authority = authority,
              RedirectUri = redirectUri,
              PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
              TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
              {
                 RoleClaimType = "roles"
              }
            });
}
```

**Current solution** with undesirable dual sign in

1. Front-end web app *(OWIN/MVC/JavaScript)*

   - Owin handles AAD authentication
   - MVC generates views **based on the authenticated** user
   - ADAL JS handles user authentication client-side and acquires an access token that is added as a cookie (my_access_token)
2. Back-end web app *(OWIN/SignalR PersistentConnection)*

   - OWIN handles authentication by extracting the access token found in the my-_access_token cookie and adding it as a Bearer Authorization header
   - Authorization is handled by overriding the Authorize function in *PersistentConnection* **based on the authenticated user**

**Current Front-End Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureAuth( IAppBuilder app )
   GlobalFilters.Filters.Add( new AuthorizeAttribute() );
   app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType( CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
   app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
   app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
       new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
           {
              ClientId = clientId,
              Authority = authority,
              RedirectUri = redirectUri,
              PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
              TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
              {
                 RoleClaimType = "roles"
              }
            });
}
```

**Current Back-end Startup.cs**

```
public void Configuration( IAppBuilder app ){
   app.Use( ( context, next ) =>
       {
          if (context.Request.Cookies.Any(c => c.Key.Equals("BearerToken")))
          {
            var cookie = context.Request.Cookies.First(c => c.Key.Equals("BearerToken"));
            context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", new[] { $"Bearer {cookie.Value}" });
          }

           return next.Invoke();
        });

    app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
        new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
           Tenant = tenant,
           TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                                         {
                                             ValidAudience = audience,
                                             RoleClaimType = "roles"
                                          }
        };
     );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It's possible. You need to specify the shared key for cookie encryption & decryption. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1

once your added AzureAd you just inject the shared cookie setting with the shared cookie name and the dataProtectionProvider from the same key in both apps.